# MySQL : Having a table with minimum and maximum value columns, how could I find the "highest" values if my search term exceeds maximum value?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Sorry if my question is a bit confusing, but database design (nor queries) are not my strong points.

Let's say I sell a product, which are cables. And those products have three "variations", which 
prices would be applied in layers like 'post-processings':

- Type 1: Ordinary cable.
- Type 2: Ordinary cable plus custom color.
- Type 3: Ordinary cable plus custom color plus terminals.

Also, the final price of the cable will depend on the length, and the more meters of cable you buy, the less price per meter I will apply.

So, I've designed a `cable_pricings` table like this:

```
id|product_id|product_type_id|min_length|max_length|price|
--|----------|---------------|----------|----------|-----|
 1|         1|              1|         0|        10| 0.50|
 2|         1|              1|        10|        20| 0.45|
 3|         1|              1|        20|        40| 0.40|
 4|         1|              1|        40|        50| 0.30|
 5|         1|              1|        50|        60| 0.25|
 6|         1|              1|        60|         0| 0.15|
 7|         1|              2|         0|        10| 0.35|
 8|         1|              2|        10|        20| 0.30|
 9|         1|              2|        20|        40| 0.30|
10|         1|              2|        40|        50| 0.20|
11|         1|              2|        50|        60| 0.20|
12|         1|              2|        60|         0| 0.20|
13|         1|              3|         0|        10| 0.40|
14|         1|              3|        10|        20| 0.40|
15|         1|              3|        20|        40| 0.30|
16|         1|              3|        40|        50| 0.30|
17|         1|              3|        50|        60| 0.25|
18|         1|              3|        60|         0| 0.25|
```

Now with this structure, let's say I want to buy 47 meters of cable, with custom color. With a single query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM cable_pricings
WHERE product_id = 2
AND product_type_id IN (1,2)
AND min_length <= 47
AND max_length > 47;
```

I got two rows which will hold those type of cable and be in the length intervals, then on my server code, I iterate over results and get final price. Up to here, everything good.

But my problem is on the "edge" cases:

- If I want to buy 60 meters of cable, my query won't work, as `max_length` is `0`.
- If I want to buy more than 60 meters of cable, my approach won't work as well, because in that case none of the conditions will apply.

I've already tried with MAXs, MINs, but I'm not getting the expected results (and I think aggregate functions check the whole table, so I'd like to -*if that's possible*- not to use aggregates).
I also thought to put on the 'edge' `max_length` the value of `9999999` but I think that's just... a *dirty* fix. Also, this will be managed from a backend, and I don't expect the final user writing lots of `999999`s on edge case.

Then my questions are:

- Can I solve "edge" cases with a single query? Or I have to split my cases into two separate queries?
- Is my table design correct at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change

```
AND max_length > 47
```

To:

```
AND (max_length > 47 OR max_length = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wozuld use this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM cable_pricings
WHERE product_id = 1
  AND product_type_id IN (1,2)
  AND min_length >= 60
  AND (max_length > 60 OR max_length = 0);
```

[dbfille exampole](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8e5a2711d943cf4d324ba7ab37f4cb19)

You have to include the null else the max restriction will not trigger